# Sendgrid inbound webhook data entirely blank in Flask but works with a request sent from requests?

Tags: python, flask, sendgrid

I have a heroku flask app up right now. When it receives a POST request, it uses the sendgrid API to send an email to my personal email containing the POST data. Relevant code (driver.sendgridemail is the example code for python written with https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) with a string passed as an argument:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    driver.sendgridemail("Data is here: %s" % (data)) 
    return data
else:
    return render_template("index.html")
```

When I POST using requests.post:

```
requests.post("my_heroku_url", data=json.dumps({"some":"data"}), headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})
```

I get an email to my personal email containing "Data is here: {"some":"data"}"

However, when I use the sendgrid inbound parse feature, the only email forwarded to my personal email is  "Data is here:" which is obviously not ideal.

Does it have to do with content-type? Why isn't it processing the data from incoming email messages? It's obviously getting the email because it's capable of being forwarded to my personal email per flask app, it just doesn't retrieve the data. In other words, the POST request goes through but it's unable to retrieve any data and gives me a blank binary string. Finally, isn't it a little weird that is still thinks it's b" ? Does that mean it never gets decoded to a string with the sendgrid parse, but it does with a python requests post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html):

> The request that will be sent to the HTTP endpoint will be encoded as multipart/form-data.

You need to use the `request.form` dict to access form-data in Flask.

A tutorial is available on Sendgrid's blog: https://sendgrid.com/blog/collect-inbound-email-using-python-and-flask/

Additionally, when you make that change, you should remove `headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}` from your `requests.post` call, so that you send it as form-data too.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but requested a form which I converted to a dict. The webhook now works like a charm. I also recommend you use ngrok to test the endpoint as sendgrid requires you to expose the url.

```
data = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
```